# Is there any possible thing to do if I strongly disagree with a moderator?

Tags: discussion

I found a programming solution that I wanted to share in a question. Then I realized that the question was asked multiple times with with some little variations but in general with the same idea.

Since I wasn't able of marking questions as duplicate and in that moment I ignored that I was able to flag them, I copy-pasted my first answer to the other questions.

Some minutes after, a moderator deleted all my posts and quoted:

> If you're able of copy-pasting the same answer, then you should instead flag the questions as duplicated.

I agreed and I flagged:

- *[Is there a standard way to create Debian packages for distributing Python programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110604/is-there-a-standard-way-to-create-debian-packages-for-distributing-python-progra)*
- *[Debianzing a Python program to get a .deb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401381/debianzing-a-python-program-to-get-a-deb)*
- *[Making a .deb file from a Python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770883/making-a-deb-file-from-a-python-file)*
- *[How to make .deb file from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323107/how-to-make-deb-file-from-python)*

as duplicates of: *[How do I do Debian packaging of a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382569/how-do-i-do-debian-packaging-of-a-python-package)* and I also flagged that my answer on the main question could now be un-deleted.

Then, I was really surprised when a moderator refused my flag and quoted

> Your edit leaves your answer not addressing the actual question being
>   asked here. It's not asking about how to build a Debian package in
>   general.

Well I strongly disagree. I ignore if they have ever built a Debian package with a python script or if they even read my answer, but it is sure that their comment makes no sense.

I'm surprised that moderators have the time to delete and answers as un-helpful, but not to mark as duplicate the ones that I tagged (even if one of it has 32 votes).

I find all this frustrating. I think that the moderator could have deleted some of the copy-paste but at least let the main answer since it is a very helpful answer.

Am I wrong? Did I miss something?

Comment: "That if i can copy-paste an answer, the threads should be flagged as duplicated" I strongly disagree with that sentence. Just because *some* answers are valid for two questions doesn't mean that all answers to those questions are valid for both questions, which is the requirement for a duplicate. For example one of the questions might have additional requirements such as performance or security.

Comment: @CodesInChaos in which case the same answer wont satisfy the other question

Comment: but you flagged to an admin for a duplicate? they usually don't process that. Better leave a comment "possible duplicate of xxxx" even if you don't have the rep.

Comment: @Janar Some answers might fulfill the requirements of both questions, some answers will only be valid for one.

Comment: Determining that you copy-&-pasted your answer as multiple answers on different questions is trivial to determine without any subject matter expertise. The normal thing to do is delete such answers. That was done. Determining which questions are actually duplicates of each other usually requires subject matter expertise, which you should not assume the moderator has. Thus, it's quite reasonable for them not to close those questions as duplicates. As others have said, closing as duplicate is usually left to the community to do, unless the moderator is also subject matter expert.

Answer (score 13):

I guess the question I'm left with is *"do we really need multiple new duplicate answers on a question that has been asked multiple times and was already adequately answered ages ago?"*

If you really feel the need to post your solution, post it *once*, to the question you feel that it most adequately addresses.

Comment: The moderator has a point; it's not acceptable to copy/paste a general answer to several *specific* questions.  That's backwards.  The right way is to post the general answer to a general question about packaging, or whatever this is about.

Comment: If you're asking a moderator to take action on your post *based on its technical content,* you're barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Moderator flags should only be raised for issues which the user community cannot handle itself.  In this particular case, it was most likely a flag that was automatically raised by the software when you started copy/pasting answers.  This is not something that you need a moderator to fix; just find the *one* question where you'd like to post your answer, and repost it there.

Comment: To point out why moderators don't generally handle technical merit issues-  there's a handful of moderators and a lot of things in the world to know.  The odds that the moderator who gets to your flag knows enough to think about technical merit is low-  most programmers don't know anything about python and even fewer know debian packaging.  That's why they let the community deal with that-  people gravitate twoards tags they are experts in, and can make better decisions than a random mod.